# Toggle elements based on selector number

Tags: jquery, selector

I know there is a better way to do this!

```
$('.press-125').click(function(){
    $('.fullpress-125').slideToggle();
});

$('.press-128').click(function(){
    $('.fullpress-128').slideToggle();
});
```

...and so on. Hope someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: can you change the html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the html use a common class and a data-* property like

```js
$('.press').click(function () {
    $('.fullpress-' + $(this).data('id')).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="press" data-id="123">123</li>
  <li class="press" data-id="125">125</li>
  <li class="press" data-id="126">126</li>
  <li class="press" data-id="127">127</li>
  <li class="press" data-id="128">128</li>
  </ul>

<div class="fullpress-123">123</div>
<div class="fullpress-125">125</div>
<div class="fullpress-126">126</div>
<div class="fullpress-127">127</div>
<div class="fullpress-128">128</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It also posiible

```
$('[class^=press]').click(function(){
    $('.fullpress-' + $(this.attr('class').split("-")[1])).slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you use IDs instead of class attribute, but this should work

```
$("[class^='press-']").click(function(){
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.full'+className).slideToggle();
});
```